# How not Javascript printing my textbox button and print my photo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, printing, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have a MVC view and view as like this. Print this picture and I do not want to appear when the Button and TextBox.
This code only works but does not print CSS.
and my view and javascript print for code like that

```html
@model dynamic
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutAdmin.cshtml";
}

<link href="~/print.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <div class="event-container">
        <div class="row">
            @foreach (var item in Model.JoinData)
            {
                BLL.Concretes.OrderDetailRepository ord = new BLL.Concretes.OrderDetailRepository();
                var olacak = ord.GetWithDeleted().Where(x => x.Order.Chair.ChairNo == item.ChairNo && x.Order.Chair.Table.TableNo == item.TableID).GroupBy(x => x.Product.ProductName).Select(x => new
                {
                    Urunadi = x.FirstOrDefault().Product.ProductName,
                    SiparisMiktari = x.ToList().Count()

                }).ToList();
                <div id="@item.ChairNo@item.TableID" class="item col-xs-12">
                    <div class="event-item wow fadeIn animated" data-wow-delay="0.1s">
                        <div class="event-place">
                            <b>Masa:</b>@item.TableID<br />
                            <b>Ürünler :</b><br />
                            @foreach (var item2 in olacak)
                            {
                                @(item2.SiparisMiktari + "*" + item2.Urunadi) <br />

                            }
                            <strong>Fiyat:</strong><div id="olacak">@item.Fiyat</div>
                            <strong>Miktar:</strong><b id="s2">@item.Miktar<br /></b>
                            <input type="button" value="Sandalye Ödemesi Yap" class="btn" onclick="onayla(@item.ChairNo,@item.TableID)" />
                        </div>
                        <strong>Verilen Para:</strong>@Html.TextBox("VerilenParaSandalye")<br />
                        @Html.ValidationMessage("VerilenParaSandalye", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <input type="submit" value="Fişkes" class="btn" onclick="onay(document.getElementById('VerilenParaSandalye').value,@item.ChairNo,@item.TableID,@item.Fiyat)" />
                        <div class="event-time">
                            <span class="event-month">Sandalye</span>
                            <span class="event-date">@item.ChairNo</span>
                        </div><!-- /.event-time -->
                    </div><!-- /.event-item -->
                </div>
                <input id="maradaona" type="hidden" name="name" value="@item.ChairNo@item.TableID" />
            }
        </div><!-- /.row -->
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">


    function onay(VerilenParaSandalye, ChairNo, TableID, Fiyat) {
        $.post(
                '@Url.Action("validate", "Kasa")',
                { VerilenParaSandalye: VerilenParaSandalye, ChairNo: ChairNo, TableID: TableID },
                function (VerilenParaSandalye) {
                    $.call(VerilenParaSandalye, function (index, county) {
                        var toPrint = document.getElementById(ChairNo + "" + TableID);
                        var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank');
                        popupWin.document.open();
                        popupWin.document.write('<html><head><title>HotCatCafe</title><link href="~/print.css" rel="stylesheet" /><img src="~/Content/images/logo.png" /></head><body onload="window.print()">')
                        popupWin.document.write(toPrint.innerHTML);
                        popupWin.document.write('Verilen Para : ' + VerilenParaSandalye + '<br/>');
                        popupWin.document.write('Para Üstü : ' + (VerilenParaSandalye - Fiyat));
                        popupWin.document.write('</body></html>');
                        popupWin.document.close();
                    }
                    )
                }
            );
    }
    if (Session["VerilenParaSandalye"] == document.getElementById('maradaona').value) {
        function onayla(ChairNo, TableID) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("SandalyeTopluOdeme", "Kasa")" + "?ChairNo=" + ChairNo + "&TableID=" + TableID,
                success: function (ids) {

                    $("#" + ChairNo + TableID).fadeOut();
                }
            })
        }
    }
</script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

and my print and style css

this is print css

```html
@media print 
{
    .btn
    {
        display: none;
    }
    .event-place
    {
    width: 25%;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
 
    }
   
}
@media screen
{
    .btn
    {
        display: none;
    }
    .event-place
    {
        width: 25%;
    }
}
```

and this style css

```html
@media screen /*--This is for Print--*/
{
    .btn {
        display: block;
    }

    .event-place
    {
        width: 25%;
    }
}
```

as a result How do I get my photo to appear. and I don't want seeing of the TextBox and Button.

Comment: help ! not to appear textbox button and to appear my image !!

Answer (score 0):

You load the print.css style sheet prior to the style.css style sheet. Since you're using media directives in both, there shouldn't be an issue but I'd load the print style last. Also, can you use a tool like FireBug to determine if the styles are actually loaded?

I ran the code sample and I see that the class of "btn" is applied to the submit button, but I couldn't verify that the CSS files were actually loaded.

You're on the right track of using the display: none; style for print media. There has to be a problem with loading the page or the style sheet to prevent the proper application of the style to the button.

I did notice a syntax error in the line:

url: "@Url.Action("SandalyeTopluOdeme", "Kasa")" + "?ChairNo=" + ChairNo + "&TableID=" + TableID,

You appear to have an additional quote after the closing parenthesis after Kasa.

Should it read:

url: "@Url.Action("SandalyeTopluOdeme", "Kasa") + "?ChairNo=" + ChairNo + "&TableID=" + TableID,

Good Luck!

Comment: not work url: "@Url.Action("SandalyeTopluOdeme", "Kasa") + "?ChairNo=" + ChairNo + "&TableID=" + TableID, :S